# How I can run a Python automatically when you start or restart android-mobile-phone?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, console

I have a python script that reads a database and sends a sms per record (droid.smsSend (number, text)) found, but I run it manually searching for the script and executing it.

I would like to set an option in the android mobile phone for every time you start or restart automatically start the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating an app, adding the permission RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and then creating a receiver for that intent, for example:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.BootBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Finally code your class com.example.BootBroadcastReceiver to launch the script.